# How to handle error without crashing function with axios?

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-promise

So the problem is, that in some function i want to call `getRecord` function. It's making request with axios. Some times request can be faild, so i want to handle the error without crashing my function, where i'm calling `getRecord.`

I'm calling getRecord like this:

```
  const res = await getRecord(eventData)
  console.log('handleReadyToRemoveCalls -> res', res)
```

Here is the getRecord function

```
const getRecord = ({ extTrackingId, targetId }) => {
  console.log('getRecord -> executed')
  const apiConfig = require('../config')

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `https://cloudpbx.beeline.ru/apis/portal/v2/records/${extTrackingId}/${targetId}/download`,
      responseType: 'stream',
      headers: {
        'X-MPBX-API-AUTH-TOKEN': `${apiConfig.token}`,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('getRecordsReference -> response', response)
        resolve(response)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('getRecordsReference -> err', err)
        reject(err)
      })
  })
}
```

With this approach i'm suddenly for me getting crashes, when request with axios fails. What's i'm doing wrong?

Comment: you need to catch your possible error and handle it accordingly using a `try {} catch {}` statement. you can consult [this article](https://itnext.io/error-handling-with-async-await-in-js-26c3f20bc06a) from my quick google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rejecting the promise in the `catch` block:

```
.catch((err) => {
     reject(err)
})
```

Thus your propagate the error. If you want the function not to fail just return something that is not an error like an empty array. For instance:

```
.catch((err) => {
     resolve([])
})
```

One **other way** to handle this is to reject as you do and to catch the error higher with a try catch like this:

```
try {
  const res = await getRecord(eventData)
} catch(err){
  // do whatever you want in case of an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround with try catch.

```
try{
  const res = await getRecord(eventData)
}catch(err){
//say dispatch a function and say please try again in UI
}
```

In you promise you are rejecting the with an error. That error needs to be handled in the block you are calling the function.